# How I can update an array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of person objects. In the below code, I am updating 3 fields of person object on a condition. Here What I need is, First set all these values to person object(`person.setcheckId("20")`) and set the person object to array instead of directly updating the array....

```
for (int personIndex = 0; personIndex < personArray.length; personIndex++)
     {
         if(personArray[personIndex].getId==1)
           {

         PersonType person = personArray[personIndex];            
         personArray[personIndex].setMemberId("20");
         personArray[personIndex].setName("Robert");
         personArray[personIndex].setFName("Pole");

           }


    }
```

Comment: and what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What's the problem with directly updating the object in the array?

Comment: This didn't update your array of objects ah?

Comment: 1) maybe getId is a getter 2) maybe there is no id == 1 3) maybe id is not an int?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this....but i need to modify it as mentioned above

Comment: what on earth does `and set the person object to array instead of directly updating the array....` mean?

Comment: This sounds like a badly paraphrased homework questions. VTC

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, what you can do is to first create the `Person` object and set its attributes:

```
PersonType person = new Person();            
person.setMemberId("20");
person.setName("Robert");
person.setFName("Pole");
```

and then assign it to the corresponding position in the array:

```
personArray[personIndex] = person;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PersonType person = new PersonType();
person.setMemberId("20");
person.setName("Robert");
person.setFName("Pole");

for (int personIndex = 0; personIndex < personArray.length; personIndex++)
{
    if(personArray[personIndex].getId==1)
    {

        personArray[personIndex] = personType;            

    }

}
```